# This computer's always belonged to me

Tags: present-perfect, adverbs

The word "never" negates all the time, and any time up to now in the present perfect tense.

> This computer's never belonged to me.

If I want to express the opposite of the meaning, which adverbs can serve the purpose? Can "always" do? Or forever, all the time?

> This computer's always belonged to me.

> This computer's forever belonged to me.

> This computer's belonged to me all the time.

Answer (score 8):

*Always* is the appropriate choice. *For ever* (as one word or two) usually refers to the future, but when speaking of the past it implies a *very* long time.

> Susie is my childhood friend - we've known each other *forever.*

*All the time* refers to a specific period of time.

> He was there for two hours and I watched him closely all the time. (throughout those two hours).

Comment: In your example for "all the time", I would probably use "the whole time" instead. I mostly use and encounter "all the time" meaning "frequently and continually but not continuously", as in "I go to that restaurant all the time". I'm not sure if that's an AmEng thing though.